# Can I create Multiple projects in a .Net MVC Core Web Application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need a Solution with one main .Net Core Web Application and areas to be created, but each areas has to be a .Net Core Web Application. The reason I need this is, the projects in the area needs to have separate dll and other supporting files in the bin of Main project.

Is that possible in .Net Core ?
If so, I have tried to imply the same, but each project is created with a Main method in Program.cs, which fails my build stating "Multiple entry points in my solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need [Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx). This will let you group and separate your Areas into different folders and then move these into different [shared projects or portable libraries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/04/21/sharing-code-across-platforms/). You can then reference and use these in your Main .NET Core Web App.

These are not standalone Web Applications as you asked for, but it's the best way i can think of, in order to separate the different components in your application.

Answer (score 0):

**There can only be one entry point in a C# program.**

If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point. For more information, see /main (C# Compiler Options).